# Connect R to SQL Server in MAC

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, database-connection, rodbc

I want to connect R to SQL Server on my MAC (El Capitan). I can do it very easily in Python, but in R I can't do it.

In Python it is easy as:

```py
import pymssql
pymssql.connect(server = 'CHWN-DSX-DB02', user = 'XXXX',password ='XXXX',database = 'Info')
```

For R, I tried with the RODBC library, but it didn't work.  I think the problem is the "Driver":

```r
driver.name <- "SQL Server"
db.name <- "Info"
host.name <- "CHWN-DSX-DB02"
port <-""
server.name <-"XXX"
pwd <- "XXX"
# Use a full connection string to connect to a SAMPLE database
con.text <- paste("DRIVER=",RMySQL::MySQL(),
                  ";Database=",db.name,
                  ";Server=",host.name,
                  ";Port=",port,
                  ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP",
                  ";UID=", server.name,
                  ";PWD=",pwd,sep="")

con1 <- odbcDriverConnect(con.text)
```

This code in R never ends, and when I stop it, I have this warning:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) :
> [RODBC] ERROR: state 00000, code 0, message [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(SQL Server, 6): image not found

Comment: You're correct, the problem is the driver. MySQL is not MSSQL. [See if this helps](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/).

Comment: Are you required to use the textual DSN? I can connect with `DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", database="dbname", server="ip.ad.dr.ess,1433", uid="me", pwd="secret")`. Your driver name will likely be different, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for some of that (if you are not sure).

Comment: I'll try your helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your current setup:

1. **General vs. Specific APIs**: In Python you are using a specific SQL Server API: `pymssql`. In fair comparison to your R attempt, you should be using the ODBC API: `pyodbc` (to compare with `RODBC`). Remember there are multiple ways to connect to backend databases or data stores from client applications either by specific APIs or generalized APIs (ODBC, OLEDB, JDBC, etc.).
2. **Required Drivers**: To use any ODBC library be it Python, R, or other language, you need to have an installed ODBC driver on your client machine. Download such drivers *before* attempting connection. Nearly every RDBMS or data store maintains (usually free to download) ODBC drivers for Windows, Mac, and Linux OS's including SQL Server: [2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339) or [2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).
3. **Mixing R Libraries**: In R, most APIs follow the DBI standard including `ROracle, RJDBC, odbc, RMySQL, RPostgreSQL, RSQLite`. Unfortunately, `RODBC` does not follow this standard. Your attempted connection appears to be an attempted `DBI` connection using the `RMySQL::MySQL()` object which *even* in `DBI` is not part of an ODBC connection string.

   Note even though both require underlying ODBC drivers (see #2), `RODBC` is a different library and implementation than `odbc`. Additionally, do not conflate specific APIs such as `RMySQL` with an attempted general SQL Server ODBC. In fact, it is unclear why you use RMySQL when you have a variable for `driver.name`. Also such a value, `'SQL Server'` is the Windows ODBC driver name and not macOS or Linux names. See below R ODBC connections:

   **RODBC**

   ```
   driver.name <- "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"      # REQUIRES DOWNLOAD
   driver.name <- "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"      # REQUIRES DOWNLOAD
   ...    
   con.text <- paste0("driver=", driver.name,
                     ";database=", db.name,
                     ";server=", host.name,
                     ";port=", port,
                     ";protocol=TCPIP",
                     ";UID=", user.name,
                     ";PWD=", pwd)

   conn <- odbcDriverConnect(con.text)
   ```

   **odbc**

   ```
   conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver = driver.name,
                     server = host.name, port = port, database = db.name
                     uid = user.name, pwd = pwd)

   # ALTERNATIVE:
   conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = con.text)
   ```